# Having Trouble Outputting Data correctly From SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to outputting data from a SQL table

Table cols are:

sheduleID, userID, empID, timeSlot, WeekSlot, daySlot

---

Connecting to DB

```
$schedQ = "SELECT * FROM seo_schedule WHERE empID=1 AND weekSlot=1";
$Em1Wk1Res = mysql_query($schedQ) or die(mysql_error());
```

---

Displaying Data

```
echo "<div class='week1'>";
    while ($Em1WkRow = mysql_fetch_array($Em1Wk1Res)) {
        $clientQ = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE userID=".$Em1WkRow["userID"]."";
        $clientRes = mysql_query($clientQ) or die(mysql_error());
        $clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($clientRes);
        echo "<div class='day".$Em1WkRow["daySlot"]."'>";
        if ($Em1WkRow["timeSlot"] == "am") {
            echo "<span class='".$Em1WkRow["timeSlot"]."'>";
            echo $clientRow["company"];
            echo "</span>";
        }
        else if ($Em1WkRow["timeSlot"] == "pm") {
            echo "<span class='".$Em1WkRow["timeSlot"]."'>";
            echo $clientRow["company"];
            echo "</span>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
echo "</div>";
```

---

Current Output

```
<div class="week1">
     <div class="day1">
           <span class="am">Company 1</span>
     </div>
     <div class="day1">
           <span class="pm">Company 1</span>
     </div>

     <div class="day2">
           <span class="am">Company 2</span>
     </div>
     <div class="day2">
           <span class="pm">Company 2</span>
     </div>
     ...etc fir rest of days in week 1
</div>
```

---

What I want to be displayed is:

```
<div class="week1">
     <div class="day1">
           <span class="am">Company 1</span>
           <span class="pm">Company 1</span>
     </div>

     <div class="day2">
           <span class="am">Company 2</span>
           <span class="pm">Company 2</span>
     </div>
     ...etc fir rest of days in week 1
</div>
```

How do I go about doing this....?

Comment: Can you post both table structures? It's probably possible to simplify your solution by doing a single query to fetch the data in the right format, and avoid any nested code loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing...

```
function emp_schedule($empID) {
    $weeks = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    foreach ($weeks as $i => $week) {
    $schedQ = "SELECT * FROM seo_schedule WHERE empID=$empID AND weekSlot=$week";
    $Em1WkRes = mysql_query($schedQ) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<div class='week'>";
    echo "<div class='head'><span class='ts'>Wk ".$week."</span> <span>Monday</span> <span>Tuesday</span> <span>Wednesday</span> <span>Thursday</span> <span>Friday</span></div>";
    echo "<div class='ts'><span><strong>AM</strong></span><span><strong>PM</strong></span></div>";
        while ($Em1WkRow = mysql_fetch_array($Em1WkRes)) {
            $clientQ = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE userID='".$Em1WkRow["userID"]."'";
            $clientRes = mysql_query($clientQ) or die(mysql_error());
            while($clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($clientRes)) {
                $schd = "<div class='".$Em1WkRow["timeSlot"]."'>";
                $schd .= "<span class='client'>".$clientRow["company"]."</span>";
                $schd .= "</div>";
                $days = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
                foreach ($days as $i => $day) {
                    if ($Em1WkRow["daySlot"] == $day && $Em1WkRow["timeSlot"] == "am" ) {
                        echo "<div class='day ".$Em1WkRow["daySlot"]."'>";
                        echo $schd;
                    }
                    if ($Em1WkRow["daySlot"] == $day && $Em1WkRow["timeSlot"] == "pm" ) {
                        echo $schd;
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Mess I Know but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested while to go through the days of the week rendering `<span />`s inside the week container. I'm not a php dev so can't help you with the implementation, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The question is do these events depend on a specific time or are you just trying to throw them in 1 company event per day AM and PM? In which case, you can just do:

```
$arr = array(0 => "am", 1 => "pm");
echo "<div class='week1'>";
while($Em1WkRow = mysql_fetch_array($Em1Wk1Res)) 
{
    $clientQ = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE userID='" . $Em1WkRow["userID"] . "'";
    $clientRes = mysql_query($clientQ) or die(mysql_error());
    $i = 0;
    $out .= "<div class='day" . $Em1WkRow["daySlot"] . "'>"; // start day
    while($clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($clientRes) && $i < 2) 
    {
        // add current day's event
        $out .= "<span class='" . $arr[$i++] . "'>";
        $out .= $clientRow["company"];
        $out .= "</span";
    }
    $out .= "</div>" // end day
}
echo $out; // display all week's info
echo "</div>"; // end week
```

Comment: The crux of the difference is that he's nesting while loops so you have more than one `span` per `div`.

Comment: So, the problem is your `$Em1WkRow` is not being updated each time you loop through the clients. Can you store this "am"/"pm" information elsewhere? Or maybe you need to reconsider how you have your code lined up. Can you give more information on what is in seo_schedule ?

Comment: There is nothing else in it, apart from my data they are the only cols.

Comment: I basically have 40 rows, each row has a unique scheduleID, a userID (representing s client), a empID (representing an employee), a timeslot (am or pm), a week slot (1,2,3 or 4) ad a day slot (1,2,3,4 or 5)

Comment: is your goal to assign a client to an "am" and "pm" timeSlot for each day of the week?

Comment: ideally yes, I would like a 1 div for the day and then an am and pm span in side the day.

Comment: You'll have to help me out, this solution assumes that you are only going to be scheduling 2 events per day, 1 in the AM, 1 in the PM. It will leave all other clients in the dust for that particular day. If you want clients to overlap into other days, you will need to make an adjustment.

Comment: ok, well there is four weeks on the schedule, week1, week2, week3, week4. in each week there is 5 days, each day has an am and pm timeslot. 

week 1, day 1 would have: am slot = company name pm slot = company name | week one, day 2 would have: am slot = company name pm slot = company name and so on for the rest of the week. - this will repeat four time for a four week schedule.